# I want to hide error and throw my own message in jmeter for Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException

Tags: jmeter

I am capturing URl and path from s3URL from previous response. Some time S3URL not generated then URL and Path not found. In this case i want to hide error because it is application issue not scripting issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with Adding Beanshell PostProcessor as a child of the request which must be successful and put the following code into "Script" area:

```
if (prev.getResponseCode() == "Non HTTP response code:java.net.URISyntaxException"){
        prev.setResponseOK(); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) as a child of the request you would like to mark as passed
2. Tick `Ignore Status` box if you want to mark sampler as passed

   [image]

---

Alternatively you can amend the message using [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial/) and the following code:

```
if (prev.getResponseCode().equals('Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException')) {
    prev.setSuccessful(true)
    prev.setResponseCode('Your custom response code')
    prev.setResponseMessage('Your custom response message')
}
```